# Concatanating a new object

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to add a single item to an array created by ToArray(), unfortunately i can't find any valid way to just add a new object, here's what i've tried so far:

```
List<MyObject> MyList = new List<MyObject>();
MyList.Add(new MyObject { MyParam = "1" });

MyList.ToArray().Concat(new MyObject { MyParam = "2" });
```

I don't seem to be able to concat the new MyObject directly, is there any way of doing this?

i know i could create a array and use concat to add Array A to Array B but in my full implimentation i need to create a new object under the Concat method.

Maybe Concat isn't even the right way forward? Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Arrays are not resizable.  You should use `List<T>` instead of the array.

Comment: Are you combining them in one index?? MyList is already a list of MyObject. If you are trying to add more to it, just go MyList.Add(new MyObject{MyParam = "2"});

Comment: May be you want to replace your `MyList.ToArray()` call with `MyList.ToList()` call and then use the `List.Add` method to add the item

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what it is exactly you're trying to do. If you need a resizable ordered collection, then `List<T>` is better to use than an array. To add an item, you just call `Add()`.

In the code you posted, the `Concat()` method is an extension method that returns a *new* enumerable object. It doesn't modify the original. If you want an array, and you really want to use `Concat()`, you can do something like this:

```
MyObject[] array = MyList.Concat(new [] { new MyObject { MyParam = "2" } }).ToArray();
```

Why you might prefer that to this, I don't know:

```
MyList.Add(new MyObject{ MyParam = "2" });
MyObject[] array = MyList.ToArray();
```

Seems to me that the latter is better, as it's more efficient and more clearly expresses what you're actually doing.

If you really want an array and *only* an array, you can use `Array.Resize()`:

```
MyObject[] array = new [] { new MyObject { MyParam = "1" } };

Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + 1);
array[array.Length - 1] = new MyObject { MyParam = "2" };
```

I would strongly discourage the use of code like that. It's an incredibly inefficient way to manage resizable collections. But it would work and frankly is what most closely adheres to the specification you *seem* to be asking for.

If the above is not enough information to address your concern, please improve your question by editing it to describe more clearly what it is you *do* want to do.